# javascript round problems

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I've some problems with javascript.

If I do this:

> alert(6.000 * 1.050);

I expect 6.3, but I get 6.30000001

can anybody help me ? or explain why this happens?

Comment: That's just down to how floating point numbers are represented and is not limited to javascript. For details, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can simple use the method `toFixed()` in java-script

```
alert(parseFloat(6.000 * 1.050).toFixed(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

They're called `float`s, and sometimes have a little bit of inaccuracy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_proble

Comment: okay, but how can I solve this?

Comment: @Ruutert Your question is a duplicate. Please see the link under your question for solutions and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Standard problem; decimals can't be stored with infinite precision in general, so most programming languages have data types that approximates them and show a rounded version. Problem is that multiplication or subtraction can cause the inaccuracies to show.

In the end, you'll just have to round probably.